# extracting a json response in scrapy

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, scrapy

How do you use Scrapy to scrape API that uses JSON format? The JSON looks like this:

```
  "records": [
    {
      "uri": "https://www.example.com",
      "access": {
        "update": false
      },
      "id": 17059,
      "vid": 37614,
      "name": "MyLibery",
      "claim": null,
      "claimedBy": null,
      "authorUid": "3",
      "lifecycle": "L",
      "companyType": "S",
      "ugcState": 10,
      "companyLogo": {
        "fileName": "mylibery-logo.png",
        "filePath": "sites/default/files/imagecache/company_logo_70/mylibery-logo.png"
      }
```

I tried this code:

```
import scrapy
import json


class ApiItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    Name = scrapy.Field()


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'API'
    allowed_domains = ["site.com"]
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('pages.txt').readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        item = ApiItem()
        item["url"] = jsonresponse["uri"]
        item["Name"] = jsonresponse["name"]
        return item
```

"Pages.txt" is a list of API pages that i want to scrape and i only want to extract "uri" and "name" and save it to csv.

But it throws an error saying:

```
2017-08-18 13:23:02 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.investiere.ch/proxy/api2/v1/companies?extra%5Bimagecache%5D=company_logo_70&fields=companyType,lifecycle&page=8&parameters%5Binclude_skipped%5D=yes> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 651, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/habenn/Projects/inapi/inapi/spiders/example.py", line 22, in parse
    item["url"] = jsonresponse["uri"]
KeyError: 'uri'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the example given, it should be like this:

```
item["url"] = jsonresponse["records"][0]["uri"]
item["Name"] = jsonresponse["records"][0]["name"]
```

**EDIT:**

To get all `uri`s and `name`s from the response, use this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    for record in jsonresponse["records"]:
        item = ApiItem()
        item["url"] = record["uri"]
        item["Name"] = record["name"]
        yield item
```

Note particularly replacing `return` with `yield`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks @Tomáš

Comment: Just one more thing, there are around 20 "uri" and "name" in that json, is there any way to loop that code?